# Get title from website from webBrowser in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I'm creating an app for the windows phone platform, and need to get the websites title as the user navigates through the web. 
 I have tried many ways, but it just doesn't seem to work. Any ideas ?

This is what i have :

```
String title = (string)browser.InvokeScript("eval","document.title.toString()");
```

Comment: please, provide what you already try.

Comment: String title = (string)browser.InvokeScript("eval","document.title.toString()")

Comment: Try replace String title = (string)browser.InvokeScript("eval","document.title.toString()") to String title = (string)browser.InvokeScript("eval",document.title.toString())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why the above answer was accepted as the right one:

The following line should work:

string webTitle = (string)Browser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.title.toString()");

if you call this in the **navigated** event it may not work, you MUST call this in **Browser_LoadCompleted** event, because only here all background processes finished and the invokeScript would work